# Parsing complex log file with awk or sed or other

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have log file like this:

```
 ZZ nickname1: sometexthere17 Jan 10:19PM - ZZ nickname2: sometexthere19 Jan 11:19PM - ZZ nickname3: sometexthere20 Jan 09:21PM - ...
```

`ZZ static value
nickname dynamic and I need to print
after : sometexthere dynamic and I need to print
after text there is no space and it is date value(17 Jan 10:19PM -)
- is a separate`

I need to print output to csv file like this:

`Date;Nickname;Text
17 Jan 10:19PM;nickname1;sometexthere
...`

I can use `awk -F` for parsing same separate. How can I use awk or sed for my example?

I think I need to print after `ZZ` before `:` for nickname. Print after `:` for text.

But how can I parse text and date value?

Comment: can sometext contain `- or :` ?

Comment: @Kent, no. But contain number. But not number last 2 character(before day value)

Comment: Is the day of date always on 2 chars ?

Comment: @Tensibai it should be, otherwise how would we parse `123415 Jan 10:19PM` `15 Jan or 5 Jan`?

Comment: And can the text contain spaces ?

Comment: @kent  indeed, it was the reason of my question :)

Comment: Yes, always 2 chars. And text contain space but Kent's solution works fine for me.

Comment: What have you tried? There is an extensive tutorial on sed here http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

give this line a try:

```
 awk -F': ' -v RS="-" -v OFS=";" 
      '{sub(/ZZ /,"",$1);n=length($2);
        sub(/\n/,"",$2); d=substr($2,n-14);
        s=substr($2,1,n-15);print d,$1,s}' logFile
```

the magic number `14` is the length of date string, E.g. `17 Jan 10:19PM`

Comment: Simplest than mine I think, posting an answer for advices on it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Mine for advices, BIG drawback it does not handle space in `sometext`

`awk -F' - ' '{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){ split($i,x," "); printf("%s %s %s;%s;%s\n",substr(x[3],length(x[3])-1), x[4],x[5],substr(x[2],0,length(x[2])),substr(x[3],0,length(x[3])-1))} }' test`

What's done:

`-F' - '` split fields on space - space

`for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)` Loop over the fields

`split($i,x," ");` Create a new array from each field (ZZ [...])

`printf("%s %s %s;%s;%s\n"` prepare the output

`substr(x[3],length(x[3])-1)` First %s, the day, last 2 chars of 3rd from split

`x[4],x[5]` the next two %s, month and time

`substr(x[2],0,length(x[2]))` the nickname minus the : at end

`substr(x[3],0,length(x[3])-1))` the text field, minus the 2 chars of the day

Comment: Getting error: `awk: warning: escape sequence \-' treated as plain -'`

Comment: Just suppress the \ before it, unsure why I set it at first. But this has a drawback, it was more for an advice from others than a correct answer @Kent answer is cleaner